# Clicking on hidden menu gives unknown error

Tags: python

Estoy scrapeando la web nowgoal.com. Si vas a un partido cualquiera que aparece en la pagina principal, por ejemplo https://www.bola009.com/ tienes varias tablas. Cada tabla tiene a la derecha una serie de opciones a la derecha de la columna Away. Cuando intento seleccionar una opción de las disponibles, obtengo el siguiente error.
WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.117)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
En teoría el código es sencillo. Selecciono la tabla, dentro de la tabla selecciono el menú desplegable, lo despliego con un click (hasta ahí sin problemas), busco la opción que deseo (bien) pero al darle a click salta el citado error.

Alguna idea? Es por las versiones de Chrome y chromedriver? Salvo por eso, todo lo demás se ejecuta sin fallo. Un saludo y gracias